# Rails - Including a custom array in with result of render json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization

I'm trying to merge a custom array with the result of render json.

```
render json: @value, each_serializer: JsonApi::ValueSerializer
```

and the array is `a = [1,2,3]` .

with the result of this json is it possible to append the array?

The array will be constructed into json as

```
 "a":{"1": "one","2":"two", "3": "three"}
```

Normally the json value from serializer is

```
'{"data":{"value_id":"1","attributes {{"id": "1","email":"tech@sample.com","access_locked":false},{"id": "2","email":"tech2@sample.com","access_locked":true}}}'
```

The final needed result after appending "a" json with normalized value is

```
'{"data":{"value_id":"1","attributes {{"id": "1","email":"tech@sample.com","access_locked":false},{"id": "2","email":"tech2@sample.com","access_locked":true}}, "a":{"1": "one","2":"two", "3": "three"}}}'
```

Comment: Could you add an example of the JSON you want to generate? What key should the array be put in?

Comment: Edited the question to explain my query.